# Como forçar uma rota aninhada a utilizar o mesmo nome de parâmetro da rota pai?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Meu esquema de rotas tem a necessidade de adicionar 3 novas rotas para actions personalizadas em minha controller: **start**, **cancel** e **finish**.

```
resources :disputes do
  scope module: :dispute, except: :index do
    resources :conference, shallow: true, shallow_prefix: :dispute do
      put :start
      put :cancel
      put :finish
    end
  end
end
```

O problema é que ao invés de utilizar `:id` é utilizado `:dispute_id`. Para resolver isso fiz a adição manual de cada rota:

```
resources :disputes do
  scope module: :dispute, except: :index do
    resources :conference, shallow: true, shallow_prefix: :dispute
  end
end

# REVIEW: Existe uma melhor maneira para fazer isso?
put 'conference/:id/start', to: 'dispute/conference#start'
put 'conference/:id/cancel', to: 'dispute/conference#cancel'
put 'conference/:id/finish', to: 'dispute/conference#finish'
```

O que de fato não ficou elegante. Agora, é possível resolver isso sem a necessidade de escrever manualmente cada `put`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução é simples e está na [própria documentação de rotas](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions). Basta adicionar a chamada a opção `on: :member`:

```
resources :disputes do
  scope module: :dispute, except: :index do
    resources :conference, shallow: true, shallow_prefix: :dispute do
      put :start, on: :member
      put :cancel, on: :member
      put :finish, on: :member
    end
  end
end
```

Isso irá informar ao Rails que a rota faz parte (membro) do resource pai.